# ConvertFrom-StringData fails casting to Hashtable

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, hashtable

I just tried to adapt [the scripting guy's example](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/01/17/simplify-powershell-hash-table-creation-with-a-simple-cmdlet/) to read data from a textfile and parse a hashtable using `ConvertFrom-StringData`:

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion;

[String] $loginsFileName = "$HOME\Logins.txt";

Get-Content $loginsFileName;

[Hashtable] $logins = Get-Content -Path $loginsFileName | ConvertFrom-StringData;

Write-Host got $logins.count lines from $loginsFileName;
$logins.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name;
```

I got screwed up:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
3      0      -1     -1      

Lisa=GanzGeheim
Susanne=ganzgeheim
Fritz=geheim
Hans=Geheim

Der Wert "System.Object[]" vom Typ "System.Object[]" kann nicht in den Typ "System.Collections.Hashtable" konvertiert werden.
In Zeile:11 Zeichen:1
+ [Hashtable] $logins = Get-Content -Path $loginsFileName | ConvertFrom-StringData ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

got 0 lines from E:\Users\Christian\Logins.txt
```

My guess: The piping goes wrong. I tried to stress out that Get-Content delivers an array by embracing (Get-Content -Path $loginsFileName) – without any bettering. Can anybody please give me some hint?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry about misleading you earlier. The issue you are having is that you are getting an array of single key hashtables because of `Get-Content`. For what I think you are looking for you should read in the file as one string. Assuming you have at least PowerShell v3:

```
$logins = Get-Content -Path $loginsFileName -Raw | ConvertFrom-StringData;
```

This was you get one single hashtable as supposed to an array of hashtables. This gets me once and a while since PowerShell groups the output well.

`-Raw` is a feature of 3.0. If you do not have access to 3.0 than either of these solutions would suffice.

```
$logins = Get-Content -Path $loginsFileName | Out-String | ConvertFrom-StringData;
$logins = ((Get-Content -Path $loginsFileName) -join "`r`n") | ConvertFrom-StringData;
```

Comment: If you can't use the `-Raw` switch you should be able to do `(Get-Content -Path $loginsFileName) -Join "`r`n"` instead to get the same result.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I am wondering at what point I should stop mentioning about 2.0

Comment: It doesn't matter, because whenever you do stop you'll find somebody 8 minutes later that is using it. I imagine when Win7 goes out of support would be safe, because I think everything past that had PowerShell 3 by default (except Vista, and do we really care about Vista?)